# Mostrar dato entero en gráfico hecho con Angular-nvD3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Implementé un gráfico con Angular-nvD3, pero no logro cambiar el formato de los números de decimal a entero.

[image: Gráfico]

La idea es que en todos lados se vea un entero, tanto en el costado izquierdo como al pasar el mouse sobre la gráfica.

Dejo el código en cuestión:

```js
app.controller('getdatos', function ($scope) {
        
        $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'discreteBarChart',
                height: 300,
                width: 500,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 50,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){return d.label;},
                y: function(d){return d.value + (1e-10);},
                showValues: true,
                valueFormat: function(d){
                      return d3.format(',.0f')(d);
                    //return d3.format(',.0f')(d);
                },
                duration: 500,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Llamantes'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Cantidad de llamados',
                    axisLabelDistance: -10
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno Amigos, ya lo he solucionado. Mirando otros ejemplos de gráficos hechos con nvd3 llegué a la solución de agregar al eje Y, una función que lo formateara (tickFormat)

```
yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Cantidad de llamados',
                axisLabelDistance: -10,
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    //return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
                    return d3.format(',.0f')(d);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

En la opción `valueformat` estas seteando el valor en formato decimal. Solo tienes que retornar `d3` tal cual como está sin darle formato.

Comment: Saludos Amigo, gracias por darte el tiempo de responder. El value format me devuelve el valor que va encima de cada barra del gráfico (29,16,7) en formato entero. Con eso no hay drama, de hecho si lo cambio solo a <d3> me deja de mostrar ese valor y me muestra un objeto nulo. Lo que no logro cambiar son los numerales del costado izquierdo, no sé si tal véz tendré que tocar la libreria en si para cambiar eso.